# basetime for strftime segment filename template

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a big mp3 file, which I started recording at 17:24. Trying to split into 2 minute segments:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp3 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 120 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 '1/test-%H-%M.mp3'
```

Need segment names like `test-17-24.mp3, test-17-26.mp3, ...`, Actual first segment is named as current time, no extra segments created

```
$ date
Tue May 12 06:52:04 MSK 2015
$ ffmpeg -y -i test.mp3 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 120 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 '1/test-%H-%M.mp3'
ffmpeg version N-72058-g3ecc063 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
Input #0, mp3, from 'test.mp3':
  Duration: 05:45:05.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 171 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 171 kb/s
[segment @ 000000000051d560] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, segment, to '1/test-%H-%M.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.33.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, 171 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=N/A time=00:13:07.87 bitrate=N/A
video:0kB audio:16211kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
$ ls 1
test-06-52.mp3
$
```

Comment: I think you have to write a shell script that uses ffmpeg's options `-ss` and `-t`.